# Spectral of a connected d-regular bipartite graph

Tags: spectral-graph-theory

Let $G$ be a connected $d$-regular bipartite graph. 
Would you please tell me about  the spectrum of this graph?

Comment: Such a question is either too vague or not of research level. Please consider posting such questions on Math.Stackexchange. There are many books about the spectra of Graphs. I would recommend:
Cvetkovic / Rowlinson / Simic
An Introduction to the Theory of Graph Spectra

Answer (score 1):

Here a few facts:

1) since $G$ is bipartite, its spectrum is symmetric with respect to the origin;

2) since $G$ is $d$-regular, its largest eigenvalue equals $d$; combining with 1) the smallest eigenvalue is then $-d$

3) if you let $diam(G)$ denote the diameter of $G$ and $\lambda_k(G)$ the $k$th eigenvalue is non-increasing order, then for any fixed positive integer $k$, you have

$$ \liminf_{diam(G)\to \infty} \lambda_k(G)\ge 2\sqrt{d-1}$$

(this is an instance of the more general Alona-Boppana theorem)